Logic App Standard: extension bundle doesn't support connecting to the storage account using Managed Service Identity
I have a Logic App Standard with two workflows, one uses a manual trigger and the other a timer trigger. Both run successfully locally in VSCode. Once deployed to Azure, the function app fails with the following error:
Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage: Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'connectionString').
It seems that the extension bundle in use doesn't support Managed Service Identity (MSI) when connecting to the storage account, here is my host.json:
{
  "version": "2.0",
  "logging": {
    "applicationInsights": {
      "samplingSettings": {
        "isEnabled": true,
        "excludedTypes": "Request"
      }
    }
  },
  "extensionBundle": {
    "id": "Microsoft.Azure.Functions.ExtensionBundle.Workflows",
    "version": "[1.*, 2.0.0)"
  }
}

I have added the following application setting already but it doesn't seem to be supported:
AzureWebJobsStorage__accountName=storageaccountname
Any guidance or advice in where to look in order to find out where the problem is?
Note that there is a policy in place preventing the use of access keys for storage accounts hence the need to connect using MSI.

Are you calling function app in your logic app workflow? If not then how are you getting function app fails error? @JCallico

Are you talking about using user assigned managed identity in logic app standard or you are just deploying the two workflows directly to a standard logic app created in Azure portal which is using storage account connection string in AzureWebJobsStorage field. I have this values in Environment variables and deployed the two workflows to Logic app which worked for me

@IkhtesamAfrin the later but note that using the AzureWebJobsStorage field is not an option since it requires the access keys to be provided and those have been explicitly disabled.

So you don't want to use connection string in AzureWebJobsStorage field? If yes then do you want to use user assigned managed identity?

I would like to use the system assigned managed service identity for the resource itself when connecting to the azure storage account.

Unfortunately for now only user assigned managed identity is supported in standard logic app, refer this doc https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/create-single-tenant-workflows-azure-portal#set-up-managed-identity-access-to-your-storage-account which says the same

Standard logic app by default connects to storage account using connection string but if you would like to use identity based connection then you need to go for user assigned managed identity as of now user assigned managed identity is only supported.
You can also refer to this MS Doc which says the same.

By default, your Standard logic app authenticates access to your Azure Storage account by using a connection string. However, you can set up a user-assigned managed identity to authenticate access instead.

In order to authenticate using user-assigned managed identity and disable the use of storage connection string, you need to create the logic app in App Service Environment v3 hosting option.
Add the below RBAC roles to user assigned managed identity instance in storage account.

Storage Account Contributor
Storage Blob Data Owner
Storage Queue Data Contributor
Storage Table Data Contributor


Add the user-assigned managed identity to your standard logic app instance.
Delete AzureWebJobsStorage from App settings and use the below given values.

AzureWebJobsStorage__managedIdentityResourceId :- Resource Id of User-assigned managed Identity

AzureWebJobsStorage__blobServiceUri :- Storage Blob Service Uri

AzureWebJobsStorage__queueServiceUri :- Storage Queue Service Uri

AzureWebJobsStorage__tableServiceUri :- Storage Table Service Uri

AzureWebJobsStorage__credential :- managedIdentity


Save the changes. You might get a message "AzureWebjobsStorage" app setting is not present. in Overview blade of your logic app but it will not affect the logic app and will work as expected.

As of 2024-12-05 this is the correct answer. System-Assigned MSI identity is not supported at the moment.
